# Traversing through a list with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My list structure is something like this:

```
<ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-list-item first-stage">
          <a href="">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="first">Stuff</td>
                    <td class="second"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
          </a>
        </li>
    <ul class="inner-nav">
            <li class="nav-list-item second-stage selected">
              <a href="">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="inner-first"><div class="icon icon-arrow-right"></div></td>
                        <td class="inner-second">Blaa</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
               </a>
            </li>
```

Here's my jQuery:

```
if $(".first-stage").click(function() {
    var nextItem = $(this).next("li").chidren(".second-stage").find("i");
    if ($(this).next(".inner-nav").is(":hidden")) {
        $(this).slideDown();
        $(nextItem).removeClass(".fa-chevron-down").addClass(".fa-chevron-up");
    } else {
        $(this).slideUp();
        $(nextItem).removeClass(".fa-chevron-up").addClass(".fa-chevron-down");
    }
)};
```

I can't get the traversing through the list to work. This is supposed to be a dropdown list. Don't mind about the "a href" around li.

Comment: `if $(".first-stage").click(function() {`....really this way.

Comment: your html seems to be invalid

Comment: This is horrid, horrid HTML, and it will cause all kinds of problems when you try to traverse and manipulate it. Use standards-compliant HTML and your Javascript life will be 10x easier.

Comment: I need to have the tables inside li.

Comment: tables in your `li` are, fine, however having `a` and `ul` elements as direct children of a `ul` element is not.

Comment: I put the a elements inside li, is it better now to traverse trough?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to amend your HTML to make it valid:

```
<ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-list-item first-stage">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="first">Stuff</td>
                <td class="second"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <ul class="inner-nav">
            <li class="nav-list-item second-stage selected">            
                <a href="">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="inner-first"><div class="icon icon-arrow-right"></div></td>
                            <td class="inner-second">Blaa</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then you can simplify your jQuery code by using `slideToggle` and `toggleClass`:

```
$(".first-stage").click(function(e) {
    var $nextItem = $('ul', this);
    var $i = $('i', this);
    $nextItem.slideToggle(function() {
        $i.toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g5Q3v/)

Comment: This works otherwise but my list structure is long and it has multiple inner uls. This shows all the inner uls at once. I want to open them "one by one". Here's an example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3BeGV/1/.